# How to delete/hide SharePoint online feature from classic site like Site Feed etc

Tags: sharepoint-online

How to delete/hide any feature (_layouts/15/ManageFeatures.aspx) like "Site Feed", "Community Site Feature" etc. permanently from SharePoint online classic site?

I didn't see any attribute or method available in PowerShell script or CSOM to achieve this.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Thanks for looking into it. I have added additional details in my post.